# request.getAttribute() method returns 500 error code

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

In my web app I generate dynamic content for id. Below my code

```
function lookup(){
<% List<UserOrganization> el = (List<UserOrganization>) request.getAttribute("uselist");%>
<% for (int i = 0; i < el.size(); i++) {%>   
        var email<%out.print(i);%>="<%out.print(el.get(i).getUser_1().getEmailId());%>";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "EveConnectOutletsCount",
            data: {
                email:email<%out.print(i);%>
            },

            success: function(data) {

                $('#ec<%out.print(i);%>').html(data)

            }  
        });
<% }%>           
}
```

**JSP page:**

```
<s:iterator value="uselist">  
      <span id="ec<%=n%>"></span>
</s:iterator>
```

This page executes fine, if `uselist` has some value. It throws 500 error code if `uselist` is empty.
How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Are you sure it throws the error if "uselist is empty" and not if "uselist is **null**", which is an entirely different thing?

Comment: Check it for null first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding below code.

```
function lookup() {
'<s:if test="uselist.size()>0">'
  <% List<UserOrganization> el = (List<UserOrganization>) request.getAttribute("uselist");%>
<% for (int i = 0; i < el.size(); i++) {%>    
    var email<%out.print(i);%>="<%out.print(el.get(i).getUser_1().getEmailId());%>";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "EveConnectOutletsCount",
        data: {
            email:email<%out.print(i);%>
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#ec<%out.print(i);%>').html(data)
        }
    });
<% }%>
'</s:if>'
}
```

so if list is `null`, my code wont generates null pointer exception.

Comment: not @dave,because i use s:if for checking the uselist is empty or not.so if uselist is empty nothing will be executed in the lookup function.then how uselist throw null pointer exception.i checked this code,it doesn't throw null pointer exception

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null reference. `size()` is a method.

Answer (score 0):

You can access request attributes from request map. Use status index if you need indexed ids.

```
<s:iterator value="#request.uselist" status="st">  
  <span id="ec<s:property value='%{#st.index}'/>"></span>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: exception throws in this line.                                          <% List<UserOrganization> el = (List<UserOrganization>) request.getAttribute("uselist");%>

Comment: Post stacktrace and remove/replace this scriptlet code if it's not working.